# Jquery Chosen add any custom value to box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-chosen

```
How can i add any custom value to box
```

Type alp in the suggestion and press enter Choosen will add alpha in the box now press backspace it will be deleted
I want to add alp as new tag not the alpha.
I had seen that in JIRA you can have the flexibility to add alp as there is a option as new lead on clicking of that alp is selected as new tag.
How can i do that with choosen ?
[Choosen Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4or7bstp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through the [jQuery Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) documentation, and it does not seem to include the requested feature, at least not out of the box.

However, you could use [Select 2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) instead. Look at the example entitled "Tagging support". The code would look like below.

**HTML**

```
<select id="demo">
    <option value="1">Alpha</option>
    <option value="2">Beta</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(".demo").select2({
  tags: true;
})
```